# Can't get Leaflet geoJSON layer to display

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

First attempt to use Leaflet geoJSON for polygons.  GeoJSON file looks good.  To keep it simple, coded this way:

```
var map = L.map( 'map', {
    center: [47.5, -121.95],
    minZoom: 10,
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [streets],
```

});

```
var myStyle = {
"color": "#ff7800",
"weight": 5,
"opacity": 0.65
```

};

```
L.geoJson(kcdfp_parcel, {
style: myStyle}).addTo(map);
```

None of the polygons display.  There are no errors indicated by FireBug.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you show us your entire code in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Never used JSFiddle before, so hope this works.  https://jsfiddle.net/d91Lryxd/11/

Comment: I believe you GeoJson coordinates are not valid. Try using www.geojson.io to test if your file is loading correctly.

Comment: geojson.io is not throwing an error, but the polygons are not displaying either.  I'll try a different ESRIjson to geoJson converter.

Comment: The ArcGIS Desktop feature to JSON tool is putting out lat/lon numbers I don't understand.  Instead of numbers like 47, -122, the format is 1288203, 136143.

Comment: Changed the projection of the map and layers to web mercator.  ESRI feature to JSON produced different lat/lon data but still not what's expected.  Now the numbers are things like -13609320, 6001744.

Comment: Further testing changing GCS, projection, and display in ArcMap.  Is it possible that ArcMap is putting out a proprietary form of coordinates?

Comment: Found it!  The numbers that become the vertices of the polygon are in units defined by the projection (e.g. feet for State Planes, meters for Web Mercator).  By changing the shape file to a GCS only (no projection), the numbers are lat/lon in decimal degrees.  Made the change and everything looks OK on the map created by Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `L.geoJSON` instead of `L.geoJson`